# Twisted Core Foundation reactor and CFNetwork in the py2app bundle

Tags: python, cocoa, twisted, pyobjc, py2app

I'm making a Python/PyObjC bundle to use some Twisted features from an Objective-C application.

I need to install a Core Foundation reactor in my Python App:

```
from twisted.internet import cfreactor
cfreactor.install()
```

The problem is that when I build a bundle with py2app, the required CFNetwork framework never appears inside my bundle and when I load the bundle from my Objetive-C application it crash.

There is any way to force link the CFNetwork framework?
Why this framework is not added automatly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including packages that aren't automaticly detected is easy: just add the missing modules to your setup.py file:

```
setup(
   ...
   options=dict(
      py2app=dict(
        includes=["module1", "module"],
      ),
   ),
   ...
)
```

I don't know why CFNetwork isn't automaticly included, the code for cfreactor shouldn't confuse py2app this way (that is, the imports are done using regular import statements and aren't hidden in C code or **import** calls).

Can you reproduce that problem using a small sample project (for example a trivial SystemPreferences plugin)? That would make it a lot easier to debug the issue.

Also, which versions of Twisted, PyObjC and py2app do you use?

Comment: I think that the problem is that pyobjc is not found in my $PYTHONPATH.
I'm testing with a simple script:

`import objc
 import CFNetwork
 print 'Hello'`

And I got a "ImportError: No module named CFNetwork" but my $PYTHONPATH contains "~/Devel/UbuntuOne/scripts/devsetup/eggs" and this folder contains "pyobjc_core-2.5.0b1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg" and "pyobjc_framework_Cocoa-2.5.0b1-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg" eggs.

Any idea?

Comment: Adding "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC" to my $PYTHONPATH all works fine, thank you for your help!